# Best way to store large amount of JSON data. MS SQL? Raven DB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, linq, ravendb

We're getting data from a webapi and we need to store the data on our server. The data have some main object types: house, housing cooperative and cottage information. Here's a short code snippet from two responses:

```
House:
 {   "advertiseOn": {
        "homepage": true,
        "showAsComming": true,
        "showTodaysHousing": true,
        "showAsReferenceHousing": true,
        "imageIds": [
          "sample string 1",
          "sample string 2"
        ],
        "documents": [
          {
            "name": "sample string 1",
            "id": "sample string 2",
            "extension": "sample string 3",
            "url": "sample string 4"
          },
          {
            "name": "sample string 1",
            "id": "sample string 2",
            "extension": "sample string 3",
            "url": "sample string 4"
          }
        ],

Housing cooperative
{
  "advertiseOn": {
    "homepage": true,
    "showAsComming": true,
    "showTodaysHousing": true,
    "showAsReferenceHousing": true,
    "imageIds": [
      "sample string 1",
      "sample string 2"
    ],
    "documents": [
      {
        "name": "sample string 1",
        "id": "sample string 2",
        "extension": "sample string 3",
        "url": "sample string 4"
      },
      {
        "name": "sample string 1",
        "id": "sample string 2",
        "extension": "sample string 3",
        "url": "sample string 4"
      }
    ],
```

In the above snippet the data for house and housing cooperative are the same but they have data that are diffrent.

If they would have had the same data it wouldnt be a problem just map them both to a Object table with a relation to each object. AdvertiseOn for example.

Since each main object have about 20-25 diffrent objects which would result in 75 diffrent database tables it just doesn't feel like the best way to solve this problem. What is the easiest way to store this data? We need to be able to search through the data with diffrent parameters. EstateId for example.

Any ideas or suggestions?
// H

Comment: How would you define 'best way'? The fastest way? The most dynamic way? The most secure way?

Comment: Really any way because im out of ideas how to store the data. I'd really like to avoid creating 75 tables in mssql

Comment: Should transactions on the database be ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability), or does it not matter.  Sometimes doing the hard work is the correct choice depending on the context of your problem (the creation of the 75 tables to store the data)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you specified it seems like any document database would fit the bill, especially ones that store Json natively. (good examples would be [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) and [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) - document databases with dynamic schema that store Json)

 Choosing a NoSQL database is mostly about the questions that you have, questions like the following:

- How do you plan to access the data? Queries? Data access patterns in general - do you need aggregations? reporting? or simple queries?
- Requirements for reliability, consistency, high-availability - does the database provide all capabilities and reliability guarantees that you need?

Also, imho choosing the right database is easier *after* you decide how exactly do you want to model your data. [This blog post](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) can provide excellent intro on data modelling in NoSQL databases.

Answer (score 1):

Michael is right, you need to understand how you will access the data and then see what are limitation of different databases. 
You can store JSON in MongoDb and create indexes optimized for JSON documents, but if you need to have some kind of joins between house and housing cooperatives you you will need to create map/reduce functions because there are no joins between collections. I think that MongoDb is still case sensitive so you cannot use collations.

If you are already using MS SQL you can even store JSON as a text. In Sql Server 2016 CTP3 will come built-in functions for parsing and querying JSON text, see [JSON in Sql Server 2016 post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jocapc/archive/2015/05/16/json-support-in-sql-server-2016.aspx). If you will use some older version of Sql Server you can use some of the existing CLR/JSON libraries such as [Sql4Json](http://www.json4sql.com/) or [JsonSelect](https://www.jsonselect.com/), or build your own library using [Json.Net](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/74160/)

There is no absolutely best way to resolve this problem, you need to analyze what platform can fit your use case.